# Compare value of the same column in PL SQL between 2 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table called ACCOUNTS which has every day data. I want to compare if there is change in email address between yesterday and today employee wise.

```
select EMAIL,EMPLOYEE from ACCOUNTS where day='30-DEC-20'; --today's data
select EMAIL,EMPLOYEE from ACCOUNTS where day='29-DEC-20' -- yesterday'data
```

I have to deal with bulk data sets here and have no clue whatsoever.

Comment: More information would be helpful.  For instance, is there only one row per employee per day?  Sample data and desired results are generally very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one row per day per employee, one method is aggregation:

```
select employee,
       max(case when date = date '2020-12-29' then email end) as email_yesterday,
       max(case when date = date '2020-12-30' then email end) as email_today
from accounts
where date in (date '2020-12-29', date '2020-12-30')
group by employee
having min(email) <> max(email);
```

If you wanted to generalize this to any day:

```
select employee,
       max(case when date = trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day then email end) as email_yesterday,
       max(case when date = trunc(sysdate) then email end) as email_today
from accounts
where date >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day
group by employee
having min(email) <> max(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

This option compares e-mail addresses between "this" and "previous" days and returns a row if they differ.

Sample data is in a CTE (lines #1 - 9) - you don't type that as you have it in your table.

Query you might be interested in begins at line #11.

```
SQL> with accounts (email, employee, day) as
  2    -- sample data; you already have that in your table
  3    (select 'scott@x.com', 'Scott', date '2020-12-01' from dual union all
  4     select 'scott@x.com', 'Scott', date '2020-12-02' from dual union all
  5     select 'scott@y.com', 'Scott', date '2020-12-04' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 'adams@x.com', 'Adams', date '2020-12-11' from dual union all
  8     select 'adams@y.com', 'Adams', date '2020-12-12' from dual
  9    ),
 10    -- query begins here
 11  data as
 12    -- fetch "today's" and "previous day's" e-mail addresses
 13    (select email todays_email,
 14           lag(email) over (partition by employee order by day desc) previous_email,
 15           employee,
 16           day
 17     from accounts
 18    )
 19  --
 20  -- display data where today's and previous day's e-mail adresses differ
 21  select employee, day, todays_email, previous_email
 22  from data
 23  where todays_email <> previous_email
 24  order by employee, day;

EMPLO DAY        TODAYS_EMAI PREVIOUS_EM
----- ---------- ----------- -----------
Adams 11.12.2020 adams@x.com adams@y.com
Scott 02.12.2020 scott@x.com scott@y.com

SQL>
```